# Vim: Error detected while processing function jedi#init_python:

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv

I'm a new vim user. I am trying to make Vim editor as python IDE. Mostly I use [virtualenv](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for python work.

So the problem is that vim-editor seems working fine in one environment while It throws an error in different env. Both environments(let's say env1 & env2) have the same dependencies. But both will show the different result for the system path.

**Env1**

```
In [1]: import sys; sys.path
Out[1]: 
['',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/bin',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_s3direct-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/amit/.ipython']
```

**Env2**

```
In [1]: import sys; sys.path
Out[1]: 
['',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/bin',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python27.zip',                                                        
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',                                               
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',                                                  
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',                               
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',                                                    
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',                                                   
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',                                               
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',                  
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',      
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',           
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',         
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',                                             
 '/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',                          
 '/Users/amit/.ipython']
```

As you can notice *Env1* have paths related **/System/Library/Frameworks/** while *Env2* have paths related to **/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/**. I didn't understand why It is happening.

When I open a file in *env1*, It open normally but when I open it in *env2* it throws a given error.

```
Error detected while processing function jedi#init_python:                                                       
line   24:                                                                                                       
Error: jedi-vim failed to initialize Python: jedi#setup_python_imports: ImportError: cannot import name _remove_d
ead_weakref (in function jedi#init_python[4]..<SNR>54_init_python[27]..jedi#setup_python_imports, line 27). See :
messages for more information.                                                                                   
Error detected while processing function LoadRope:                                                               
line    4:                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                               
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                           
  File "/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ropevim.py", line 7, in <module>         
    import tempfile                                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", 
line 32, in <module>                                                                                             
    import io as _io                                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 5
1, in <module>                                                                                                   
    import _io                                                                                                   
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: _
_PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder                                                                               
  Referenced from: /Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so                          
  Expected in: flat namespace                                                                                    
 in /Users/amit/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

The python dependencies that have in *env2* are given below

```
$ pip freeze
ipython==5.8.0
jedi==0.12.1
rope==0.10.7
ropemode==0.4
ropevim==0.7.0
```

I didn't understand, what is going wrong with env2? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.